# Bundling multiple css files for a multi tenant site?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, less, bundle, multi-tenant

Our asp.net mvc application currently has a single style for all our tenants.
We want to move to a system where depending on the tenant, a different css (actually a less variable file) is used.
The path to the file is predictable as `~\content\[tenantName]\style.css`

Is the only way to configure `[numberOfTenants]` bundles and then have:

```
<%= Styles.Render("~/content/[tenantName]/style.css")%>
```

Is there a way to serve the correct css from the same virtual path, keeping the naming convention in mind, without having to configure separate bundles and without breaking caching?

Comment: I don't see anyway around this since you a) have to serve each of these bundles to different clients at the same time and b) if you update a CSS file, you don't want to break the cache (unique key) as you mentioned.  You could simplify your logic (assuming you are manually listing each bundle) with a `foreach(var directory in StylesDirectory)` loop in your bundleConfig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a three pronged approach to do multi-tenancy in ASP.NET MVC but it is possible (I've done it myself).

- Write your own view engine that takes into account the client. You can get the client information from many places, but I usually just used the hostname. www.client.com == client-1.
- Create helper methods to identity the client. Like I said above, use the host name and it should be pretty good, but also allow yourself to hardcode a client if you need to test.
- Create a consistent folder structure to store images, css, and views.

A custom view engine will be your path to success.

Comment: thanks for your experience. I had howedver, hoped for a less involved approach. Am looking into using querystrings with css files now.

Comment: @BorisCallens There are all kinds of problems with going the querystring approach, especially if you have to keep passing it along to keep the site styled. Using HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host is your best option if you have multiple urls pointing to the same site. If all you are changing is the css file (which I bet it won't be, because different clients will want different layouts), then you don't need a view engine. Just my 2 cents from personal experience creating multi-tenant sites.

Answer (score -4):

Use ResolveClientUrl!

```
   //Returns: ../HomePage.aspx
String ClientURL = ResolveClientUrl("~/HomePage.aspx");

//Returns: /HomePage.aspx
String RegURL = ResolveUrl("~/HomePage.aspx");

//Returns: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyProject\HomePage.aspx
String ServerMappedPath = Server.MapPath("~/HomePage.aspx");

//Returns: ~/HomePage.aspx
String appRelVirtPath = AppRelativeVirtualPath;

//Returns: http://localhost:4913/
String baseUrl = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + Request.ApplicationPath;

//Returns: "http://localhost:4913/HomePage.aspx"
String absUri = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
```

Comment: I, in no way, see how this applies to the question being asked.

Comment: this feels like half an answer. not helpful at all like this.